# Get free space of a supplied drive path in powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a Function to return the amount of free drive space in MB. The function takes the path name as a parameter and must cope with mount points. My drives are set up like this:

- C:\ - Disk0
- G:\ - Disk1
- G:\Data - Disk2

So I want to do something like:

```
function Get-FreeSpace {
    param (
        $path
    );  

    # iterate through and find the volume, detect if in a mount point and return free space
    #

    return [int]$freeSpace;
}
```

I have looked at using this array as a starting point in my function, but I am getting stuck.

`$vols = Get-WMIObject Win32_Volume -filter "DriveType=3" -computer $computerName | Select Caption,DriveLetter,Label,@{Name="DiskSize(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N1}" -f($_.capacity/1gb))}},@{Name="PercentFree(%)";Expression={"{0:P2}" -f(($_.freespace/1mb)/($_.capacity/1mb))}}`

`$vols` is returning a `System.Array` of `PSCustomObject` types. So if I pass the function the following paths:

- `G:\Data\My\Test\Path`
- `G:\Data`

It will find the free space of the `G:\Data` mount point.

If I pass it `G:\Some\Other\Path`, it will return the free space of the `G:\` drive. I want to use it like so: `$freeSpace = Get-FreeSpace "G:\Some\Other\Path"`

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
function Get-FreeSpace {
    Param(
        $path
    );

    if ($path[-1] -ne '\') { $path += '\' }
    $filter = "DriveType=3 And Name='$($path -replace '\\', '\\')'"
    $free = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter $filter |
            Select-Object -Expand FreeSpace
    return ($free / (1024*1024))
}
```

You need to double the backslashes in `$path`, because they must be escaped for WMI queries. For that (confusing as it may seem) you have to replace `'\\'` with `'\\'`, because the first occurrence is a regular expression where the backslash must be escaped, whereas the second occurrence is a string literal with a double backslash.

**Update:**

To match a partial path you could use the `-like` operator:

```bsh
function Get-FreeSpace {
    Param(
        $path
    );

    $free = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType=3" |
            Where-Object { $path -like "$($_.Name)*" } |
            Sort-Object Name -Desc |
            Select-Object -First 1 FreeSpace |
            ForEach-Object { $_.FreeSpace / (1024*1024) }
    return ([int]$free)
}
```

The `Where-Object` clause selects all mount points with a partial path matching `$path`, and the subsequent `Sort-Object | Select-Object` selects the one with the longest match.

Comment: Almost! Thanks for the reply. I need it to work for sub-folders too. Read more closely the last part of my question. If I have a drive with 2GB free space as a mount point of G:\Data and I pass in G:\Data\SubFolder, I get 0 returned, and not the free space of the mount point. Similarly, your function does not work for Sub Folders of the root drive. So, if G:\Log is not a mount point and I pass that to the function, I also get 0.

Answer (score 3):

A simpler variant:

```
function Get-FreeSpace {
    param ([string]$path);
    $space = (Get-Volume -FilePath $path).SizeRemaining;
    return [int64]($space / (1024 * 1024)); # this would otherwise be a float
}
```

`Get-Volume -FilePath` retrieves the volume associated with the provided path; from that volume, we extract `SizeRemaining` and divide out 1MB. The cast to int64 is because the operation would otherwise return float.

Comment: Clean solution, but seems to work only with local paths.